# Magento 2: How to create color swatch attribute for the customer?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, customer-account, customer-attribute, color-swatches

[image]I want to create a color swatch attribute for the customer same like we use for the product attribute.

Comment: please explain in brief.

Comment: @AnasMansuri please review updated description.

Comment: You need to provide more information as to what actions you would like the swatch to do or what exactly it will be for. adding a picture is no help without a specification outlined

Comment: https://www.magevision.com/blog/post/display-gender-field-as-radio-button-magento-2/ - please check with this - its relative your issue. hope you understand.

Comment: @DavaGordon based on the selection of color by customer I want to display custom product collection as a suggestion.